# Prevent Power Users install or uninstall softwares in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, user-accounts, windows-installation, privileges

Does anyone know if it's possible to create a user account on windows 7 with custom installation/uninstallation permissions.

We have an application that requires the user to be set to Power User / Admin to run it smoothly. But I would not want this user to be able install or uninstall any other softwares

I am aware of disabling Windows Installer in GPO, but it doesn't fix my issue, there are tons of different types of installer out there which is not Windows Installer based.

I also aware of his current account priviledge will able to revert the changes I made (just presumed he is not as smart at the moment)

Changing his account type to Standard User is not an option, the software would not run correctly. Using "Run As" also does not solve the issue

Anyone know what settings I need to do here?

Comment: What permission exactly does this program need that a Power User has that User does not.  The solution is indeed group policy there really isn't another solution here

Comment: If you're scripting network installs, you should be able to allow your installation to run with admin privileges through SCCM or whatever tool you're using to deploy.  If you're just doing manual install, are you talking about an AD account, or a local account?  If local, I don't think you can't stop much unless you know the admin password to their machine, and they don't.